# Wallis Product for $n = \tfrac{1}{2}$ From $n! = \Pi_{k=1}^\infty (\frac{k+1}{k})^n\frac{k}{k+n} $

Tags: calculus

How does

$$
\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\left(\,\,\sqrt{\, k+1 \over k\,}\,{k \over k + 1/2}\,\right)
={\,\sqrt{\,\pi\,}\, \over 2}
={\sqrt{2\left(\,\pi/2\,\right)} \over 2}
={1 \over 2}\,\,\sqrt{\, 2\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
{\left(\, 2k\,\right)^{2} \over \left(\, 2k - 1\,\right)\left(\, 2k + 1\,\right)}\,}\,\ {\large ?}
$$

In other words, how do you derive the Wallis product
${\pi \over 2}
=\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
{\left(\, 2n\,\right)^{2} \over \left(\, 2n + 1\,\right)\left(\, 2n - 1\,\right)}$ from $\left(\,{1 \over 2}\,\right)!
$ 
if
$$
n!
=\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}
\left[\,\left(\, k + 1 \over k\,\right)^{n}\,{k \over k+n}\,\right]
$$

It should be possible, "[after a bit of manipulation](https://books.google.ie/books?id=N-glBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=Wallis%20product%20%28k%2B1/k%29%5En%20k/%28k%2Bn%29&source=bl&ots=LqPcd3mCGl&sig=CduC8ns8I120LWZWA8dOXNcHacY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JMCRVP2-Oov6UJWIgLgB&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Wallis%20product%20%28k%2B1%2Fk%29%5En%20k%2F%28k%2Bn%29&f=false)" but it never works!

Comment: Use $\displaystyle\verb*\prod*$ for $\displaystyle\prod$ ( which can be used with inf and sup limits ) instead of $\displaystyle\verb*\Pi*$ which yields $\Pi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
F(n)=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)^n\frac{k}{k+n}\tag{1}
$$
Then, using Stirling's Formula,
$$
\begin{align}
F\left(\frac12\right)^2
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k+1}k\frac{k^2}{\left(k+\frac12\right)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{k+1}k\frac{4k^2}{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\left(\frac{4^n\color{#C00000}{n!^2}}{(2n+1)\color{#00A000}{(2n)!}}\right)^2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\left(\frac{4^n\,\color{#C00000}{2\pi nn^{2n}e^{-2n}}}{(2n+1)\,\color{#00A000}{\sqrt{4\pi n}(2n)^{2n}e^{-2n}}}\right)^2\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2n+1}\right)^2\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi4\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
F\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\tag{3}
$$

---

**Or Perhaps...**

After I reread your question, it seems that perhaps you were looking for something like this:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac\pi4
&=\left(\tfrac12\right)!^2\tag{4a}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\sqrt{\frac{k+1}k}\frac{k}{k+\frac12}\right)^2\tag{4b}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^2}\tag{4c}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^2}\tag{4d}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\tag{4e}\\
&=\frac12\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\tag{4f}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(4a)}$: use $(2)$
$\text{(4b)}$: identity given in question
$\text{(4c)}$: algebra
$\text{(4d)}$: definition of an infinite product
$\text{(4e)}$: $\left\{\begin{align}
\textstyle\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{2k(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^2}
&\textstyle=\frac{2\cdot4}{3^2}\frac{4\cdot6}{5^2}\frac{6\cdot8}{7^2}\cdots\frac{(2n-2)2n}{(2n-1)^2}\frac{2n(2n+2)}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&\textstyle=\frac1{2^{\vphantom{1}}}\frac2{1^{\vphantom{1}}}\frac{2\cdot4}{3^2}\frac{4\cdot6}{5^2}\frac{6\cdot8}{7^2}\cdots\frac{(2n-2)2n}{(2n-1)^2}\frac{2n}{2n+1}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\\
&\textstyle=\frac{1^{\vphantom{1}}}2\underbrace{\frac{2^2}{1\cdot3}\frac{4^2}{3\cdot5}\frac{6^2}{5\cdot7}\cdots\frac{(2n)^2}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\\
&\textstyle=\frac12\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}
\end{align}\right.$
$\text{(4f)}$: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}=1$ and the definition of an infinite product

Therefore,
$$
\frac\pi2=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: Yes the edit is exactly what I meant! How did you go from $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^2}$$ to $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}?$$That's the whole source of my trouble! :)

Comment: @bobby : $\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k(2k+2)}{(2k+1)^2}=\\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2\cdot4}{3^2}\cdot\frac{4\cdot6}{5^2}\cdots\frac{2n\cdot(2n+2)}{(2n+1)^2}=\\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2}{2}\cdot\frac{2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot6\cdot6\cdots2n\cdot2n\cdot(2n+2)}{1 \cdot 3\cdot3\cdot5\cdot5\cdots(2n+1)(2n+1)}=\\ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{2\cdot2}{1\cdot3}\frac{4\cdot4}{3\cdot5}\cdots\frac{2n\cdot2n}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}\frac{2n+2}{2n+1}\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}
$

Comment: @bobby: I have added an explanation which covers this.

Comment: @SteveKass: Thanks. This being the crux of the whole question, I've included it in the explanation of $(4)$.

Comment: You guys rock!!!

Answer (score 4):

From the Euler's identity:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}z!=\Gamma(z+1) &=& \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{n! n^z}{(z+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(z+n)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^{z}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^{-1}\\&=&\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^z\end{eqnarray*}$$
it follows that:
$$\frac{1}{2}! = \prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{k}}\left(1+\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{-1}$$
or:
$$\left(\frac{1}{2}!\right)^2 = \prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}\right)^{-1}=\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(k+1)(2k)^2}{k(2k+1)^2}=\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(k+1)k^2}{k(k+1/2)^2}$$
that is just the square of our initial product. Since:
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)},$$
it follows that $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and 
$$\frac{1}{2}!=\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}$$
as wanted.