# Factorial identity $\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)!$ to get Waallis

Tags: calculus

I asked the wrong question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1072351/wallis-product-for-n-tfrac12-from-n-pi-k-1-infty-frack1k), my fault :(

How does one see, using $n! = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^n \frac{k}{k+n}$, that

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)! = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{k}{k+\tfrac{1}{2}}\right) = \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 \cdot \left(\frac{2 \cdot 2}{1 \cdot 3}\frac{4 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 5}\dotsm \right)}? $$

In other words, derive

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}\right)$$

while manipulating

$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{k}{k+\tfrac{1}{2}}\right)$$

Note this is a way to '[derive](https://books.google.ie/books?id=N-glBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA329&lpg=PA329&dq=Wallis%20product%20%28k%2B1/k%29%5En%20k/%28k%2Bn%29&source=bl&ots=LqPcd3mCGl&sig=CduC8ns8I120LWZWA8dOXNcHacY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JMCRVP2-Oov6UJWIgLgB&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Wallis%20product%20(k%2B1%2Fk)%5En%20k%2F(k%2Bn)&f=false)' the Wallis product

$$ \tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2 \cdot \left(\frac{2 \cdot 2}{1 \cdot 3}\frac{4 \cdot 4}{3 \cdot 5}\dotsm \right)} = \frac{\sqrt{2 \tfrac{\pi}{2}}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{ \pi}}{2}$$

It should follow, "[after a bit of manipulation](https://books.google.ie/books?id=VOcUBvbUXlEC&lpg=PA421&dq=Elliptic%20Integrals&pg=PA423#v=onepage&q=Elliptic%20Integrals&f=false)", but it just doesn't! I must be missing something!

**Edit:** I now think it [is not possible](https://books.google.ie/books?id=YqQA5yWE22YC&lpg=PA207&ots=luOjK2bMXf&dq=%22Wallis%20product%22%20%22gamma%20function%22%20%22infinite%20product%22&pg=PA206#v=onepage&q=%22Wallis%20product%22%20%22gamma%20function%22%20%22infinite%20product%22&f=false) directly!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to show that

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(2k)^2}{(2k+1)(2k-1)}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) uses [Euler's infinite product for the sine function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Product_representations_of_functions):

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \frac{x^2}{k^2 \pi^2}\right).$$

The result follows quickly by applying $x = \pi/2.$

Comment: No the point is to derive that infinite product from $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}\left( \frac{k}{k+\tfrac{1}{2}}\right)$ by a few manipulations!

Comment: I did the piece you needed at the end.  (Well, Euler did.  I just looked it up.)

Comment: I found an answer, a very cool one linked to above, in which we can use your step http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product#Proof_using_Euler.27s_infinite_product_for_the_sine_function.5B1.5D to justify why the infinite product involves $\pi$!